# IllegalStateException with deep stubbing in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I'm getting a very strange error with Mockito:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
  at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.remove(LinkedList.java:923)
  at org.mockito.internal.debugging.WarningsFinder.find(WarningsFinder.java:36)
  at org.mockito.internal.debugging.WarningsPrinterImpl.print(WarningsPrinterImpl.java:28)
  at org.mockito.internal.debugging.WarningsCollector.getWarnings(WarningsCollector.java:34)
  at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:29) <26 internal calls>
```

There is no reference to my test code, but here are the classes I'm using and the test:

**Endpoint.java:** Uses Retrofit 2.0

```
public interface Endpoint {
  @GET("items/{itemId}")
  Call<List<Item>> list(@Path("itemId") String itemId);
  Call<List<Item>> list(@Path("itemId") String itemId, @Path("alternativeId") String alternativeId);
}
```

**Query.java**

```
public class Query {
  private String itemId;
  // constructor, etc
  public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
  }
}
```

**ItemDataSource.java:** Unfinished implementation (following TDD)

```
  public class ItemDataSource {
    private Endpoint endpoint;
    // constructor, etc
    public Optional<Item> get(Query query) {
      List<Item> list = null;
      try {
          list = endpoint.list(query.getItemId()).execute().body();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      Template result = modelAdapter.apply(list.get(0));
      return Optional.ofNullable(result);
    }
  }
```

**ItemDataSourceTest.java:**

```
public class TemplateNetworkDataSourceTest {

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Mock
  private Query query;

  @Mock
  private Item item;

  @Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
  private ItemEndpoint endpoint;

  @Test
  public void shouldProvideItemFromEndpoint() throws Exception {
    when(query.getItemId()).thenReturn("itemId");
  when(endpoint.list("itemId").execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(singletonList(networkTemplate)));
    ItemDataSource dataSource = new ItemDataSource(endpoint);

    Optional<Item> actual = dataSource.get(query);

    assertThat(actual.get()).isEqualTo(item);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldProvideNoItemsWhenNotFound() throws Exception {
    //when(query.getProductId()).thenReturn("incorrect_productId"); // <- works
    when(endpoint.list(anyString()).execute()).thenReturn(Response.success(emptyList()));
    ItemDataSource dataSource = new ItemDataSource(endpoint);

    Optional<Item> actual = dataSource.get(query);

    assertThat(actual.isPresent()).isFalse();
  }
}
```

If I run it, the first test runs correctly but the second gives me the provided error. If I comment out the first line in the statement of the second test it works (so that could be the answer) but I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if this is a bug on Mockito.

From my slight digging through **Mockito**'s code I see that a `List` is modified when collecting the warnings after the test is executed.